# GPS location acts like it is stored in array and sent one by one on each request

Tags: android, android-intent, gps

I am building an app that sends GPS coordinates to the server on regular interval of time and stores them in database. But when saw in database I found that the gps actually sending the wrong(old) co-ordinates later.

Old means, suppose I am traveling in a car,

```
At 2:00PM the coordinates are 73.982749854638 and 99.65363535375 (suppose)
At 2:05PM the coordinates are 73.982749812343 and 99.12334567866
```

now I closed the app, and again run it at

```
6:00PM the coordiantes are 73.1234546789 and 99.123456789
```

but when I check in the server database at 6:00PM the server actually receives the the co-ordintes which are at the 2:05pm

I don't understand why this happening, below is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
protected SendLocation sendLoc;
protected DeviceInformation devInfo;
TextView txtLat, status;
Button regDevice;
ToggleButton toggBtn;
String lat, provider;
protected long minTime = 60000;
protected Double latt, lonn;
protected boolean toggle;
protected String latitude,longitude; 
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    devInfo = new DeviceInformation(MainActivity.this);
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    toggBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    toggBtn.setText("Start Tracking!");
    toggBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(toggBtn.isChecked()){
                status.setText("Tracking is Enabled!");
                toggBtn.setText("Stop Tracking!");
                status.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                toggle = true;
            }else{
                status.setText("Tracking is Disabled!");
                toggBtn.setText("Start Tracking!");
                status.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                toggle = false;
            }
        }
    });

    final Context context = this;
    regDevice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regButton);

    regDevice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Register.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    });

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latt = location.getLatitude();
    lonn = location.getLongitude();
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    if(toggle == true){
        txtLat.setText(latt+"\n"+lonn);
        String uniq = devInfo.imei;
        String aobj[] = new String[3];
        aobj[0]=Double.toString(latt);
        aobj[1]=Double.toString(lonn);
        aobj[2]=uniq;
        sendLoc = new SendLocation();
        sendLoc.execute(aobj);
    }
    else if(toggle == false){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Sending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    toggBtn.setEnabled(false);
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txtLat.setText("GPS Disabled! Please Enable GPS.");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    toggBtn.setEnabled(true);
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txtLat.setText("Click button below to start tracking.");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that time the timstamp from the location or is that captured when you receive it? All Location objects keep a timestamp and the duration in milli- and nanoseconds since system boot when it was received. In OnLocationChanged you can check this and make sure that the Location is not too old before you send it over.

EDIT:
I reread your post and it seems that the issue might also be in the location sending code. If the location outputted on your screen is timestamped by you and sent to the server then the server should receive the same information as you get on your phone. Might be a problem with your sending code.

Comment: Then it appears to be your server or the sending thing messing stuff up. If you check the Android documentation for Location http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html you will find the functions I'm talking about. What I would do in this case is to send the server a message timestamped with the time from the Location object you get. This ensures that it is actually the time that the location was fixed that will show up on the server. But be aware that the location might not match up with where the user actually is so make sure that you check it's age before sending.